# PDF is not generating with Reportico extension in Laravel

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, reportico

I install reportico extension for laravel 5. Then made a project with simple steps and get this type of screen.
http://gyazo.com/51ca5ae3785f4d419e2166076ab69624

When I click on HTML button I get results like this.
`gyazo.com/80dda2682491d096deb6f9d17aa30f3e`

But when I click on PDF button to generate PDF, I get this error.
http://gyazo.com/6df18abfe45ddbc0e85f7ba97637e7b4

Please help me here....

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved on it's Repo.

https://github.com/reportico-web/laravel-reportico/issues/2